# No sound produced through Lenovo laptop's speakers (only headphones)

Tags: windows, audio

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T580 laptop running Windows 10. For about a week, sound is no longer heard through the speakers, only through headphones, if plugged into the audio jack. Interestingly, if I play sound through some app, and look at the Sound Mixer, the level indicator is active, which suggests Windows "thinks" audio is being produced.

I've tried the following without success:

- (of course) setting the volume loud enough from both the app itself and from the Windows icon tray
- updating my audio drivers (Realtek HDA)
- switching audio output between the default speaker option and the headphones option
- disabling the speaker and the soundcard from the Device Manager, then letting them be reinstalled/reenabled again
- restarting the Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder services
- restarting Windows (after each of the other solutions tried)

Any suggestions what else I can try?

Comment: You have tried everything possible on the software side. Maybe it's time to check the hardware?

Comment: I was hoping there was something I missed :( It might be that I need to take it into a shop then..